# Jodit-react undefined property "name"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jodit

I think Jodit is not handling react event at all?

part of the code:

```
let [something,setSomething] = useState({'s':''})
let {s} = something
let handleChange = (e)=>{
        setSomething(
            {
                ...something,
                [e.target.name]:e.target.value  //error occuring here.

            }
        )

    }
```

and then when trying to rendering jsx:

```
<JoditEditor required className = 's' name='s' value={s} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}></JoditEditor
```

and in dev browser I get :

[image]

as title mentioned, and of course this does not happen with normal html element.

Comment: may you did *something* wrong in the code you didn't show, because `e.target` being `undefined` is unusual - unless `e` is not what you expect

Comment: it is only undefined for JoditEditor, as i mentioned, it works perfectly for normal html input element. Also my error does not indicate that `e.target` being undefined at all.

Comment: @Ghazi I guess [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jodit-react) is what you're using? `onChange` looks like it gives you a string back, not an event object

Comment: `my error does not indicate that e.target being undefined at all.` - well, the only use of a `name` property in **the code you posted and highlighted** is `e.target.name` ... so the error IS telling you that `e.target` IS undefined - error messages are like that - good ones tell you exactly what the problem actually is, and in this case, it is telling you that `e.target` is `undefined` when trying to access its `name` property

Comment: yes, i am using this, i am not sure what you mean that `onChange` is giving a string back

Comment: It's right there in the `usage` documentation!! the onChage event argument is the newValue, not an `event`

Comment: @Ghazi It looks like in your example `e` is a string, eg: `"hello"`, so using `"hello".target` gives `undefined`, so you're trying to do `undefined.name`. Log `e` in `handleChange`

Comment: when in doubt [read the documentation](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/examples/intergration/react-jodit.html)

Comment: @NickParsons yes!, normally it would be an `[Object object]` (event being an object), but  i am not sure how to resolve this with a wysiyg editor like jodit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props of onChange event is string content, not event.
I updated your code.

```
let [something,setSomething] = useState({s:''})
let {s} = something
let handleChange = (key, newContent)=>{
    setSomething(
       {
          ...something,
          [key]: newContent
       }
    )
}

<JoditEditor
  required
  className = 's'
  name='s'
  value={s}
  onChange={(newContent) => handleChange('s', newContent)}>
</JoditEditor>
```

Comment: good solution, except what if i have a state with several properties, 1 of them is basically a value of input element, that means it would handle change under react event `[e.target.name]`, how would i connect this to the property value of `JoditEditor`?

Comment: You can pass the key as props to handleChange method.
I updated the code.

Comment: thanks, i just realised i have to pass a custom key and value for each input in jsx :), worked fine for me.